# Missing Datetime rows after converting from object for a time series analysis on Bitcoin

Tags: datetime, time-series, data-science, bitcoin, timeserieschart

I tried to convert the column (Date) of my csv file from object (2014/09/17) to datetime (2014-09-17) but when I visualized the data from where it start until the end of 2014 (2014-12-31), it looked like there was some missing rows at the datetime because i had just 78 rows instead of 105 and the Line Chart of 2014 was a mess XD. I attached images below, so you can see everything.

This is the code i used to convert object to datetime

maindf['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(maindf['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')

y_2014 = maindf.loc[(maindf['Date'] >= '2014-09-17')
& (maindf['Date'] < '2014-12-31')]

y_2014.drop(y_2014[['Adj Close','Volume']],axis=1)

How can i fix this problem?

[Input and output after I converted to datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkZQs.png)
[Year 2014 Line Chart after the converted datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgmxf.png)
[2014 until today after the converted datetime, i still need to check the other years as well, but it looks like there are missing rows there as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaFxs.png)

I was expecting to have 105 rows of Datetime and not less. And the Linechart being nice.

Comment: I solved the issue.
First:
1) I changed from object to datetime directly from excel (I had some rows that were hiding without knowing it, so I fixed that)
2) I checked more closely the excel file where the data was and in some rows the datetime was not like this 2014-10-31 (yyyy-mm-dd) but like this  2014-31-10 (yyyy-dd-mm), so that's why the Line Chart was a mess. 
I changed all the datetime in the similar manner, and now everything is running smoothly. 
I hope this will help someone.